# Can I buy a car in New York state and drive with a full UK driving license?

Tags: usa, driving-license, uk-citizens

I have just moved to up-state New York. I'm on a J-1 non-immigration  visa, and have a full UK driving license, but not international driving permit. I'm struggling to find definite information online about the following details.

Am I permitted to:

1. Buy a car and
2. Drive the car in my current situation (or would I, for example, need to get a US driving license)?

[References would be helpful]

**Update**

This is the order I actually ended up doing things, and I didn't get into any trouble:

*Within the first 3 months*

1. Bought a car from the dealer using 6 points of ID (I actually provided more then 6) - the dealer did all the registration etc.
2. Got insurance through progressive, who let you insure a car with a foreign driving licence.
3. Got a driving permit from NY DMV.

*Within the first 6 months*

4. Took the NY driving test (after the 5-hours pre-licensing course) and surrendered my UK driving license.

Although as per the links in ViB's answer, I don't think this last step was completely necessary

Comment: This might help https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/drive-new-york-state

Comment: Comment rather than answer because this is advice that doesn't answer the question: I've looked at the law quite a bit in regard to my wife, who was living in New York with a G-4 visa.  Her reasons for considering getting a NY license were somewhat different from yours, and in the end she didn't, but one conclusion we reached that _does_ apply to you is that _it's very confusing and therefore difficult to reach firm conclusions._  I suspect that in the end you'll find it easier just to get a New York license.  I obtained a NY license "from scratch" twice: in 1985 and in 2005. ...

Comment: ... The second time, as an experienced driver, it was very simple.  If your admission is for "duration of status" (that is, "D/S" on your I-94), you'll want to avoid getting a Real ID because you'd have to renew it annually.  If I recall correctly, your having a foreign license means that you won't need to have another driver in the car after you get your learner's permit.

Comment: An international driving permit is irrelevant--they aren't actually licenses, but translations of your existing license so the local cop can understand it.  I believe you're considered a resident even though that status isn't permanent.  Local license, local insurance.

Comment: @LorenPechtel from traveller's link: _"resident" shall mean domiciliary, that is, one who lives in this state with the intention of making it a fixed and permanent abode. It shall be presumptive evidence that a person who maintains a place of abode in this state for a period of at least ninety days is a resident of this state._ So if you don't plan to stay, you're not a resident, though you might have to prove it in court.  You'll need local insurance in any event because that's where the car is registered.

Comment: @phoog Your logic would mean that someone who bought a plot of land with the intent of 40 years from now building a house and retiring there would not be a resident of their current location.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I'm just quoting the law.  I don't know how NY courts have interpreted it, or I'd've posted an answer.  I do know that someone on a J-1 visa who maintains a domicile outside the US has a much better shot than someone in the situation you've described at asserting nonresidence under this law.  With vaguely worded laws like this there's generally an individualized inquiry into the facts, not a hard and fast rule.  Furthermore, most US states, if not all, do not require university students to get local driver's licenses.

Comment: @phoog I agree with your comments here. It actually seems more clear-cut that students don't need to get a local license. I should have mentioned this in the question that my J1 is in the 'research scholar' category, not the 'student' category.

Comment: I think your best bet is to approach a dealer and ask if they can sell you a car with your foreign license.  I suppose it must be possible, because for example it ought to be possible for a foreigner who owns a second home in New York to keep a car at that home, and the car should be registered in New York even if the foreigner resides abroad and has a foreign license.  But I have no idea whether there are documentary requirements for such a transaction in addition to those required to sell a car to a New York resident.

Comment: If you buy from a dealer or seek to register the car in your own name, either the selling dealer or the state department of motor vehicles will, in order to complete the transaction, require you to show that you have the state-mandated amount of liability insurance on the vehicle.

Comment: I've just spoke to a dealer and they said I need to satisfy 6 points on the following list: https://dmv.ny.gov/registration/proofs-identity-and-date-birth-nys-vehicle-registrations-or-title-certificates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been there, Korean license in NY state.

> Drive the car in my current situation (or would I, for example, need to get a US driving license)?

Yes, you can drive here as long as you are not a NY state resident. There are many interpretations of the laws but as I understood it is referred if you spend of 3 months in the state [1].

Afterwards, you can either get a full NY driving license. Or, you can get a driving learning permit (really easy 20 questions exam) + you have to carry your international license (or International driving permit for non-english driving licenses [2].

1: https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/drive-new-york-state

2: *If I have a driver license from another country and I have a NY State learner permit, can I drive without a supervising driver?* section https://dmv.ny.gov/more-info/moving-new-york